# How to defeat the Eye of Cthulhu

Tags: terraria-console

How do I defeat the Eye of Cthulhu? I got him to half health with just a gun and a broadsword, but it became daytime.

Comment: Are you on the PC version or the console version?

Comment: Console version

Comment: @MickWilson you get him down to 0 HP. But you can play with friends to make it quicker

Answer (score 5):

**Prepare the terrain** :

- Put a campfire (liferegen)
- Put a sunflower (movespeed)
- Build an area made of rows of wood platforms

**The fight**

- Summon him @ 7:30pm
- Use piercing attack weapons
- Use a fast swinging weapon if swarmed
- Use the best armor you can afford
- Use potions (life,  ironskin, thorns)

You should also read this [**guide**](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Eye_of_Cthulhu_strategies).

Comment: Thnx man that will help.

Comment: This is a very weak answer. Perhaps you could provide detail on each point, or include information from the link?

Comment: Don't need now I beat him with my sister.

Comment: Hey @MickWilson would you mind marking his suggestion as an answer?  It would be appreciated if you are still active :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways of killing bosses is just getting better gear. If you are having a hard time defeating a boss, maybe you should start mining for better materials. The deeper you go, the better materials you find. It requires a lot of patience, and in some ways, luck.

On the actual fight itself, I would recommend using ranged weapons rather than melee, in order to avoid getting hit. Also avoid fighting him near your base/town, as he can kill npc's (I made the town underground to avoid any unnecessary fatalities.) Gear that increase your jumping, flying or movement speed should help in the fight as well.

Source: my experience with the PC version of the game.

Comment: Spelunker Glowstick are PC version only, but OP specified he play on console.

Comment: This also doesn't provide any details or strategies on actually fighting the Eye of Cthulhu.

Comment: Alright, I edited the answer a bit to have some insight on the fight.

Answer (score 1):

As an avid terraria player who's looked at the wiki, I have three suggestions.

1) Build an arena. This is typically a flat section of land, about 100 blocks wide. Have several layers of platforms about 5 blocks from each other stacking about 20 blocks high.

2) Fight the queen bee. This is crucial because if you do fight the queen bee, you can get the bee's knees bow. It's a weapon I highly recommend because ammo is cheap and damage output is high.

3) During the EOC fight, keep moving. Always always always keep moving. This gives you extra angles of fire and more ways to dodge the eyes swiping attacks, while still attacking back yourself.

Oh, and two more things, unload as many shots as you can while the eye is spinning, and shoot for the pupil.

Good luck out there, it only gets scarier.

Comment: If the player is having trouble with the Eye of Cthulhu, I somehow doubt they will do very well against the Queen Bee, who is both significantly stronger and harder to get to.

Comment: Queen bee may be harder to get to, but it is much easier than the eye because it has much less health. It's a lot of jumping, but an easy kill if you stand still.